# Html button not centering/leaving gap in between button and field

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a text field and button be aligned and centered but there is a big gap between the field and the button. Please help its driving me nuts

```css
 #recovery .button {
            color: white;
            padding: 0px 0px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 23px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="button">
    <div class="input-group">
    <span class="col-xs-4">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
       </span>
       <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Recover Password</button>
       </span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: is this what you're going for? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/OgWRRV

Comment: Check my answer hope it will help you.

Comment: Add float:left for both input and button

Comment: @MichaelCoker it is expect in the center of the page which your code take care of the gap but im still having centering problems.

Comment: @Ian like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/OgWRRV

Comment: @MichaelCoker yes! i had just figured it out thank you

Comment: @Ian sweet. I'll submit as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would restructure your HTML so that you're using .row/.col-* properly, and to center the `.col-xs-4`, add `.col-xs-offset-4`

I would use `.col-sm` and not `.col-xs` but that's up to you.

```css
#recovery .button {
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 23px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
      <div class="button">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Recover Password</button>
         </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to option to get is

**1st one**

replace class`col-xs-4` to `col-xs-12`.

```css
#recovery .button {
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 23px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="button">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="col-xs-12">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
   </span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
 <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
 Recover Password
 </button>
   </span>
  </div>
```

**2nd One**

Remove the class `col-xs-4`

```css
#recovery .button {
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 23px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="button">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
   </span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
 <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
 Recover Password
 </button>
   </span>
  </div>
```